# Flutter Deferred Not Loaded Error was thrown

Tags: flutter, dart, lazy-loading, deferred

I would like to test functions, widgets etc. from lazy loaded packages. I'm using Dart’s **deferred imports** to shrink the **main.dart.js** file.

*For example:* `import 'package:spitch/app/splashscreen.dart' deferred as splashscreen;`

But because the packages etc. are not ready I get in my tests the following error: **"the following _ Deferred Not Loaded Error was thrown building ..."**

I have not found anything in the dart and flutter docs about how to test deferred loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `.loadLibrary();` in the deferred object before rendering the widget.

Answer (score 0):

The deffered library/page should be called in async, so wrap it inside a future builder.

Good Examples:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: home.loadLibrary(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) return home.HomePage();
            return Material(child: Center(child: Text('Loading...')));
          },
        )

void get()async{
    await home.loadLibrary().then((value){
  //  Your navigation code
     push(home.HomePage(), context);
    });
  }
```

Bad Examples:

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: home.loadLibrary(),
        builder: (context, snapShot) {
        return home.HomeBasement();
      });

return FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: signIn.loadLibrary(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return signIn.SignInPage();
          } else {
            return const Txt(text: 'Loading...');
          }
        });
```

**In case you are using any linting, please make sure you are not setting any object types like void, dynamic, widget?. If you specify the type, it will throw the error.**

> Note: You must open the modified code on Incognito tab or a cache
> cleared browser, If previous app data is hosted on the page, this will
> return the old Error only. So better go Incognito